# Trying to find out how to address individual menu items using "this"

Tags: javascript, arrays, this, undefined

What I am trying to do is to log results using "this" like an array so that the number 0 logs in the console.log whenever I click the first list item, without pre-defined variables and only using one function.

```
<ul class="menuList">
    <li><a class="menuImage" onclick="openMenuItemAll();"><button>&#8250;</button>Chicken Cordon Bleu</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuImage" onclick="openMenuItemAll();"><button>&#8250;</button>Chicken Stir Fry</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuImage" onclick="openMenuItemAll();"><button>&#8250;</button>Chicken Thighs</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuImage" onclick="openMenuItemAll();"><button>&#8250;</button>Fish Fillet</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuImage" onclick="openMenuItemAll();"><button>&#8250;</button>Lasagna</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuImage" onclick="openMenuItemAll();"><button>&#8250;</button>Pizza</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuImage" onclick="openMenuItemAll();"><button>&#8250;</button>Salmon</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuImage" onclick="openMenuItemAll();"><button>&#8250;</button>Spaghetti</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openMenuItemAll(){
    var menuImage = document.querySelectorAll(".menuImage");
    console.log(this.menuImage);
}
</script>
```

I'm getting undefined in the console.log when I am trying to get the array number based on the position of the menu item

Answer (score 2):

The value of `this` depends on how the function is called.

Event handler functions will have `this` equal to the element to which the event handler is bound.

So `onclick="this /* is the element */"`

Functions called with no context (e.g. if you call `openMenuItemAll();`) have `this` equal to `undefined` (unless you fail to trigger Strict Mode, in which case it will be `window`).

---

Aside: `<a>` is for **links**. Don't use it if you aren't linking anywhere. It is **forbidden** to put a `<button>` inside a link!

---

First, fix your markup:

```
<ul class="menuList">
    <li><button>&#8250;</button>Chicken Cordon Bleu</li>
```

Note that the link is removed, and I didn't transfer the `class` because you can infer it from the class on the list itself.

Then select all the buttons:

```
const buttons = document.querySelector(".menuList button");
```

Then loop over the buttons and bind your `openMenuItemAll` function as the event handler.

```
Array.from(buttons).forEach(
    button => button.addEventListener("click", openMenuItemAll)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `this` in your function: `onclick="openMenuItemAll(this);`
Then you can get the index of the target from the array.

That being said, the onclick event will happen anytime that you click anywhere in the `<li>` element. If you only want the event to fire when clicking on the button, you need to put the event inside the button. Since the button is a child of the li, then you need to pass `this.parentElement` to pass the `<li>` to the function.

Also, since the anchor tag is not really being used for it's purpose, you can remove that entirely.

In the snippet below, I also remove the bullets in the list since the buttons really replace the need for having them.

```js
function openMenuItemAll(target) {
  const menuImage = document.querySelectorAll(".menuImage");
  const index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(menuImage, target)
  console.log(index);
}
```

```css
.menuImage{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuList">
    <li class="menuImage">
        <button onclick="openMenuItemAll(this.parentElement);">&#8250;</button> Chicken Cordon Bleu
    </li>
    <li class="menuImage">
        <button onclick="openMenuItemAll(this.parentElement);">&#8250;</button> Chicken Stir Fry
    </li>
    <li class="menuImage">
        <button onclick="openMenuItemAll(this.parentElement);">&#8250;</button> Chicken Thighs
    </li>
    <li class="menuImage">
        <button onclick="openMenuItemAll(this.parentElement);">&#8250;</button> Fish Fillet
    </li>
    <li class="menuImage">
        <button onclick="openMenuItemAll(this.parentElement);">&#8250;</button> Lasagna
    </li>
    <li class="menuImage">
        <button onclick="openMenuItemAll(this.parentElement);">&#8250;</button> Pizza
    </li>
    <li class="menuImage">
        <button onclick="openMenuItemAll(this.parentElement);">&#8250;</button> Salmon
    </li>
    <li class="menuImage">
        <button onclick="openMenuItemAll(this.parentElement);">&#8250;</button> Spaghetti
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quentin has your answer, but also consider [event delegation](https://www.google.com/search?&q=javascript%20event%20delegation) to make the code more extensible:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', showIndex, false);
}

function showIndex (evt) {
  let tgt = evt.target;
  let btns = this.querySelectorAll('button');
  for (let i=0, iLen=btns.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (btns[i] == tgt) {
      console.log('Button ' + i);
      return i;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button>&#8250;</button>
  <li><button>&#8250;</button>
  <li><button>&#8250;</button>
</ul>
```

You might also consider using an OL (ordered list) in which case the LI elements will have a *value* attribute that is their position in the list.

But I think even better is to put an attribute on each button to link to their purpose so that order doesn't matter at all so you have:

```
<button data-menuItem="123">&#8250;</button>Chicken Cordon Bleu
```

Then you can link the reference "123" to whatever (and you can still get the index if you really want).